# Google Maps/OSM - Finding records within 100 miles of an area (not a point)

Tags: mysql, oracle, google-maps, distance, openstreetmap

I would like to find all points that are within N miles of a given area.

E.g. the area is California: Find all points that are within 50 miles of the border of California (not the middle of California).

When using Google Maps the distance is calculated using 'the middle' of the given location, but I need to calculate the distance using the borders of the given location. The location could be any zip code, city or country.

Could that be done by drawing a polygon using California's coordinates on a map and calculate the distance to location B using the points of the polygon?

Is there a more elegant solution to this? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be exact 100 miles from the border? In the case of OSM you can download all data within a given bounding box (a rectangle).

Comment: Yes. In theory that could be done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your requirements  completely, but I will give it a try with different interpretations:

**1. You want to filter own map points:**
This can be done with any GIS or a own service that offers a call like my_points_in_area(bbox). Bbox means here boundingbox and is the 2x lat/lon pair describing the rectangle around your given centerpoint. If you want to be accurate and really just deliver whats within 100km, you might need to test the distance to the POIs once more, as the rectangle will also include points that are a bit more far away.

**2. You want to filter OSM data:**
You might use a reverse-geocoding service as Nominatim to get informations about points of interests that are within this distance: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Otherwise import the OSM data using osmosis to a PostGIS DB. AFAIK there is (currently) no DB tool for Oracle: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Oracle

I'm sorry if I missed your question, but then please add more details :)